# What to use for a working area when learning python and Linux/Ubuntu?

Tags: python, filesystem

I am learning python from learnpythonthehardway. In Windows I had no issues with going through a lot of the exercises because the setup was easier, but I want to learn Linux as well and Ubuntu seemed to me the nicest choice.

Now I am having trouble with setting up. I can get access to the terminal and then /usr/lib/python.2.7, but I don't know if I should save the script in this directory? 
If I try to make a directory inside this through mkdir I can't as permission is denied. I also tried to do chmod but didn't know how or if to do it.

How can I correctly save my script?  I would like to be able to run the script like this: `user@user$ python sampleexcercise.py` and have it work.

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save your code in your home directory - normally `/home/(your username)/` or `~/` for short. Once you've saved your code you should be able to call it from python by using

`$ python ~/myCode/example1.py`

if  your code was in a folder called `myCode` (also note that folder & file names are case sensitive)

You don't need to be in the directory `/usr/bin/` to run python as that folder is part of your `$PATH` - which means it's accessible no matter which folder you're in.

You may also want to use IDLE, a commonly used GUI for python. You can install it by searching in the Software Center or by running

`$ sudo apt-get install python-idle`

Comment: thanks. really helped. I was actually making the files in desktop than in the home directory...

Comment: The desktop is within your home directory :)